# Detect nearby using google maps

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, geolocation

I have a list of companies with addresses, and user, that send claims (also set their own location).

And I need to send email only for that companies which are in 20 miles near the user. How can I do that?

Comment: u r using which language currenly for this functinality

Comment: I'm able to send json to client and use Javascript or directly on server - Rails. I want to use google maps - dont care what port is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you want to use Google Maps, since you are sending emails and not displaying locations on the map, right?

I think your best answer is to convert the addresses into latitude and longitude using a geocode service, and then throw them into Mongo or other DB that supports geospatial indexing.

So in Mongo DB after geocoding, you need to convert each address into something like:

```
{email: 'foobar@foobar.com', address: 'address', loc : { lon : 40.739037, lat: 73.992964 } }
```

After that you can query the DB to pull out emails for the user, in Mongo it would be something like:

```
db.emails.find( { loc : { $near : [50,50] } } ).limit(20)
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing

Comment: Unfortunately, We use Postgres. There is an extension for it, but seems like it's overkill for our small project...

Comment: Is your server side javascript?  If so you could use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717872/geospatial-queries-in-javascript

Comment: Nope, but seems like there were proposed decisions for browser... I will try to find something ruby-oriented for that. Thanks.

Comment: It's great, do you use it? I cant tune it up. Always see "geocoded_by" method is undefined and so on..